# Java: Incorrect Output [Code placement / Reading from a file]

Tags: algorithm, java

Today I am working on a program that reads in a copy of the constitution, allows a user to input three words and have those three words checked in the file and output how many times those three specific words show up! However, I have the code correct as far as I can tell besides the proper placement of one line. I constantly output the default value of my integer which I shall post below with my code.

**Code:**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class USConstitution
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner usConst = new Scanner (new File ("constitution.txt"));

        System.out.println("Enter three words: ");

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);        

        String wrd1 = keyboard.next();
        String wrd2 = keyboard.next();
        String wrd3 = keyboard.next();     

        int num1 = 0;
        int num2 = 0;
        int num3 = 0;    

        //BREAK ---------------  

        while(usConst.hasNext()){
            String check = usConst.next();

            if(check.equals(wrd1)){
                num1++;
            }
            else if(check.equals(wrd2)){
                num2++;
            }
            else if(check.equals(wrd3)){
                num3++;
            }      
            System.out.print("The word " + wrd1 + " shows up " + num1 + " times in the file!");          
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**My output consists of the following:**

Enter three words: president java test The word president shows up 0 times in the file!

I know the other two variables aren't being printed, this output differs when I change the num1 value to 10, for example, it will output 10 instead of the actual amount of times the word was found in the file. If anyone knows what I am doing wrong here I would truly appreciate some assistance,thank you very much for taking the time to read this! Have a great day ~

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: You are breaking out of your while loop after the first iteration with "break" after your System.out.print...

Comment: Read up on object equality and equivalence. Come to think of it, practise using a process visualisation tool (debugger).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your while loop logic is wrong. You are breaking out of your while loop after the first iteration with the `break` statement

Were you meaning to pull the `system.out.print` outside of the while loop and not break unless the file has no more strings to read?

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System. in );

String wrd1 = keyboard.next();
String wrd2 = keyboard.next();
String wrd3 = keyboard.next();

int num1 = 0;
int num2 = 0;
int num3 = 0;

//BREAK ---------------  

while (usConst.hasNext()) {
    String check = usConst.next();

    if (check.equals(wrd1)) {
        num1++;
    } else if (check.equals(wrd2)) {
        num2++;
    } else if (check.equals(wrd3)) {
        num3++;
    }
}
System.out.print("The word " + wrd1 + " shows up " + num1 + " times in the file!");
```

Answer (score 0):

The flow of your program is off. You're getting 3 words from the scanner without even checking if it has more data (though this is mostly just a different issue). Then within the while loop, you simply always break at the end without going over more words from your constitution file. Also I doubt you want the println statement to be over there, because it should probably only print once you have the final result, not while you're still counting.